# Which is the best Windows XP tool for indexing the hard disk?

Tags: windows-xp, search, indexing

After trying Windows 7, I miss the start menu search in my Windows XP. I don't like the Windows XP search because I think it requires much mouse work to get a search done, and it's indexing isn't fast enough. I already tried in the past a Google tool with a global keyboard shortcut that would serve my index/search needs, but I forgot it's name. I think that tool isn't the only one in the world. Which one would you recommend for me?

Comment: "Google Desktop" doesn't do what you need?

Comment: Heh heh... no rep for me!  *smile*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Microsoft also provides the free tool [Windows Search 4.0](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/products/winfamily/desktopsearch/choose/windowssearch4.mspx), that is actually not bad. I personally prefer Google Desktop though.

Answer (score 4):

Google Desktop?  >smile<

Comment: +1, because you smiled!

Comment: Heh heh... This is one of those cases where I "answered" with a comment and should've answered with an answer. *smile*

Comment: And I was looking up links...

Comment: Here's your rep :) And I didn't post because I thought it'd get flamed...

Answer (score 0):

Your options are:

- [Google Desktop Search](http://desktop.google.com/) ([features](http://desktop.google.com/features.html))
- [Windows Search 4.0](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/products/winfamily/desktopsearch/default.mspx)

I think, it's a matter of taste. On Windows XP I would prefer Google Desktop Search.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Everything](http://www.voidtools.com/).  You won't want to use anything else.

Comment: It doesn't search file contents.

Comment: Correct.  "Everything" does not search file contents, only file and folder names.